# Menucool Imageslider showing "Slider purchase reminder"

Tags: javascript

I am using javascript image slider from menucool.com which states that it's free to use.

I have implemented effect 9 (one of the many effects) successfully on the website but occasionally it shows "Slider purchase reminder" at top left of slider area.

Does anyone have an idea why it says so and how to fix it?

Link to site: www.auficecrm.com (the site is currently under construction). Refresh it 2-3 times and you will see the above text.

Answer (score 0):

Menucool requests a pay of 20$ for each domain where you use there code, You can use if for free but will have the purchase reminder. you can see it like an advertisement of menucool

http://www.menucool.com/tooltip-menu

> **License** The Tooltip Menu does not require the Menucool Menu license. It requires the Menucool JavaScript Tooltip license ($20).